# Right click ui-sref links / new tab doesn't work as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

It's pretty standard to be able to right click or ctrl click a link and open that link in a new tab. Angular ui router ui-sref's don't honor this at all. Any ideas on how this should be done? It has to be inside the framework clearly I can't do all my links a different way.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in UI Router with Angular 1.3 that was resolved.

```
<a ui-sref="test"></a>
```

resolved to

```
<a href="/test"></a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="#/test"></a>
```

They addressed and fixed this here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1408

Download the latest version of UI-Router (https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) and update your project files to resolve this issue.